# Including style.css in Child Theme

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, child-theme, wp-register-script

Twenty Thirteen uses `wp_enqueue_style( 'twentythirteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );` in functions.php.

Wheter I use it or not use it in twentythirteen-child/functions.php the style.css from Child Theme is loaded (it is always loaded) and style.css from parent theme can never be loaded.

This is an exception to other files added via `wp_enqueue_style()`, right? It doesn't behave like all the other scripts and style files that are added with `wp_enqueue_script()`.

So, I can't load parent's style.css in the child theme other than via `@import`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`get_stylesheet_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri) will return the current theme's stylesheet-- the *child* stylesheet if it is a child theme. While not entirely clear from the Codex entry for that function, it is clear from the entry for [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), which is used by [`get_stylesheet_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri). What should be happening is that the child stylesheet is being `enqueue`d twice under different slugs.

To get the parent stylesheet you need to enqueue the parent sheet with [`get_template_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri), which always returns the parent.